# Does clonezilla format the destination HDD?

Tags: format, clonezilla

I want to make an image of my OS partitions. I just have a HDD with important data on it here which i won't format because of it's data.

Now I want to know if clonezilla formats the destination HDD or if it just adds some data in form of compressed .zips or so on?

Answer (score 1):

Clonezilla has many modes of operation. What you probably want to do is to copy a disk or partion to an image. In that case it will not format the destination disk.

It can also copy a disk to another disk. Then it will destroy the content of the destination disk. It will warn you before...